# What's the difference between integer and integer[] in PostgreSQL 9.5?

Tags: postgresql, integer

please show some patience with the spelling.

So I am a bit of newbie in programming and I was trying to make a new column over a table in my pgAdmin III through PostgreSQL, when I saw there were two types of integer to select of. **Integer** and in **integer[]**.

Is there any difference between those two?

[Creating Table in PostgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHwCm.png)

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: `integer[]` is an array: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is probably just integer:

`integer[]` is an array of integers.